# How do you count the number of permutations that don't match?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose we have a list $(1,2,3,4)$. The goal is to count the number of permutations of an $n$-element list such that no permutations *match*.

A permutation *matches* another one if you can achieve one by simply flipping the other. For example, $(1,2,3,4)$ matches $(4,3,2,1)$, and $(1,3,4,2)$ matches $(2,4,3,1)$. In general, every permutation must represent a list where the elements have different "neighbors." For example, $(1,3,4,2)$ is the same as $(2,4,3,1)$ because in both lists, $1$'s neighbor is $3$, $3$'s neighbors are $1$ and $4$, etc.

Comment: If you are talking about neighbors, you can look at circular permutaions, and if right and left don't matter, then I would have $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ instead of the answer posted by 'I want to make games'

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you can just divide all permutations into pairs $(a,b)$ where $a$ matches $b$ and $b$ matches $a$. Therefore you can create $\frac{n!}{2}$ permutations such that no two match, by taking one from each pair.